# Problem with query. Looking for an elegant method to solve it

Tags: mysql

I have three tables in the following form.

```
C  
1
2
3
4

B
1
2
3
4
5


 A B C 
 1 1 1
 2 1 2
 3 1 3
 4 1 4
 5 2 1
 6 2 2
 7 3 1
 8 4 1
 9 5 1
```

And want to show list with all "B" who do not have corresponding "C". For example:

```
 -----------
 |2|3,4    |
 |3|2,3,4,5|
 |4|2,3,4,5|
 |5|2,3,4,5|
 -----------
```

I do not have much experience with sql. I'll be glad of any assistance or prompting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested but I think something like the following should work.

```
SELECT  b.B, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(c.C) AS C
FROM    tableB b
        CROSS JOIN tableC c
        LEFT JOIN tableABC abc ON abc.B = b.B
                                  AND c.C = abc.C
WHERE   abc.B IS NULL
GROUP BY b.B
```

**Edit:** Though bizarrely [it appears](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) as though MySQL has redefined `CROSS JOIN` to mean the same as `INNER JOIN` so you might need to achieve the `CROSS JOIN` by using `tableB b, tableC c` instead of `tableB b CROSS JOIN tableC c`

Answer (score 0):

You will probably be looking for something along the lines of:
(assuming the table numbers are fields called 'id'), and the A table is (id, b_id, c_id)

While more information would be helpful, this might give you some information to work with

```
    SELECT B.id, group_concat(A.id) 
    FROM A 
    LEFT JOIN B on A.b_id = B.id 
    LEFT JOIN C on A.c_id = C.id
    WHERE 
    A.c_id IS NULL
    GROUP BY B.id
```